# Remove web part of url in web.config for Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, web-config, iis-7.5

I'm using IIS7.5. Root directory is mapped to a path 'wwwroot', under which I have directories containing individual websites.

Just started working through the documentation for Symfony 2. The symfony site is under a folder called 'Symfony', ie 'wwwroot/symfony'.

I can access a path on this site using url: `symfony/web/controller/param`

How can i get rid of the 'web' part so it is: `symfony/controller/param`?

Here is relevant part of web.config:

```
<rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(web/)(.*)$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="web/app_dev.php?{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
</rule>
```

I tried this and it ain't working:

```
<rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(/)(.*)$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="web/app_dev.php?{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should point your IIS root directory of website to your `web` directory (not symfony root directory). This will remove `web` from your url and (more important) this is adviced because of security reason - only `web` directory should be accessible

EDIT:
If you do not want to change your wwwroot then I would advice to use symbolic link in windows (`mklink` command) and create a link called `symfony` under your wwwroot directory pointing to your symfony's `web` directory (in this scenario it does not matter where your symfony project is).

Then you can access `/symfony` url and symbolic link will redirect you to your `web` directory

Comment: Noted. However, it is on a developer machine and security is not a concern. Root directory is pointed up one level form Symfony and I would like to keep it that way so as to have access to multiple sites under root directory in a quick and easy manner.

Comment: Unfortunately proposed solution does not work. Created symlink, tested it and it points to the web folder correctly. Trying to navigate in browser gives 404. I think it is because web.config is under symfony folder (one level up) which is now not accessible.

Comment: I guess `web.config` is a equivalent of `.htaccess`? If so, it should be in your `web` directory. Try to type `/symfony/app_dev.php` or `/symfony/index.php` - if this works it's .htaccess issue